# How to configure Ruby to use the correct gemset or Ruby version on a per-project basis?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I open a terminal and navigate to my project folder (ex: `cd /proj/tickecting_app`).
After this I execute this command: `rvm use ruby 1.9.x@gemset` .

I want this command to run this every time I open the terminal.

Is there a way to run this automatically? And to be more specific I navigate to different projects in separate tabs.

For example:

- First tab `cd /proj/tickecting_app` and run `rvm use ruby 1.9.x@gemset`.
- Second tab `cd /proj/rss_feed_app` and run `rvm use ruby 2.1.x@gemset`.

I want to run different commands depending upon the project. Is this possible?

Comment: this question didn't used to be *how to configure `Ruby`*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using RVM then it is just a matter of putting a file named `.rvmrc` in your project directory with the following content:

```
rvm use ruby 1.9.x@gemset
```

For your second project it is the same, just change the `rvm` invocation.

Comment: Thank you for trying to solve the OP's underlying problem.

Comment: @jabbrwcky outstanding....a separate badge should be given for that ;)

Comment: If I recall correctly, `.rvmrc` is deprecated. Use `.ruby-gemset` and `.ruby-version` instead.

Comment: @Ajedi32 For me using the new version instead of `.rvmrc` doesn't automatically switch to the projects gemset. Just found this out today. :/

Comment: @pattulus It does for me...

Comment: @Ajedi32 I'm sorry for the panic. My shell profiles got messed up. `rvm get stable --auto` fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Aliases can be of use to you. You can create `alias` for each specific directory and the command you need to run. So for the two example you have given it would be:

```
alias ticketapp='cd /proj/tickecting_app && rvm use ruby 1.9.x@gemset'

alias feedapp='cd /proj/rss_feed_app && rvm use ruby 2.1.x@gemset'
```

So next time you only need to give the `alias`(no need to give `cd` either) i.e `ticketapp` and `feedapp` in the above case.

To make your aliases permanent, simply:

> vim  ~/.bashrc

and give those alias commands as-is in the `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 3):

```
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ PS1=$PS1'$(
    [ ${last_hist=\!} -ne \! ] && {
    h=$(history 1)
    [ -n "${h#"${h##* cd *}"}" ] &&    
    . ./.dircmd >&2 2>/dev/null        
})${0##*["$0"$((last_hist=\!))]*}'
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ cd .
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ 
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ echo

[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ cat <<\DIRCMD >.dircmd
echo this is my home directory
> DIRCMD
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ 
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ echo

[mikeserv@localhost ~]$ cd .
this is my home directory
[mikeserv@localhost ~]$
```

Something like that should work for a POSIX system - though I think only `bash` requires the \backslash before the !bang like that. `bash` also seems to update the history in a way that doesn't work with `fc` - which is portable - but does work with `history`. In other shells the `history 1` bit should be exchangeable with `fc -l -1` but `bash` does it a command behind, I guess. It was pretty frustrating.

Anyway, every time the prompt is drawn it defines the variable `$last_hist` as the history number for the last command. It does this in the match field on a parameter substitution that will always equal nothing so that doesn't show in the prompt.

The `fc` check just makes sure that the last history number actually incremented - as in, you didn't just hit enter or whatever. It also checks that the last command was a `cd`. If both are true it tries to `.` source a file in the current directory named `.dircmd`. If it exists it runs. If not, oh well.